# Dot in sitemap generated URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sitemap

I use `sitemap` gem to generate my `sitemap.xml.gz` : `https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator`

But when the file is generated, I have an issue in the generated links.

I have `xxxx.com/posts.10073` but the proper link is `xxxx.com/posts/10073`

This is the part of my `sitemap.rb`,

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add root_path, :changefreq => 'weekly'
  Post.find_each do |post|
    add posts_path(post), :changefreq => 'dayly', :lastmod => post.updated_at if post.published?
  end
end
```

How can I get proper link?

Comment: What does `posts_path(post)` return?

Comment: check what you get by `app.posts_path(id: post.id)` in `rails console` (get Post object in `post` variable first)

Comment: the return is : "/posts?id=12"

Comment: so try `posts_path(id: post.id)` instead of `posts_path(post)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my fault, i have make a mistake in my path, it's not posts_path(post) but post_path(post), now it's working, with the good Url.

Thank's for your answers.